# How to change the navigation menu

Tags: menus, navigation

I am fairly new to wordpress but i am having trouble working out how to customise navbar .I have added a new page.I created a new about us page.How to change the navigation bar of my about us page. Where can i get the source code of the page for about us page.Please help me i am new to word press. Any[![enter image description here][1]][1] help will be highly appreciated.I am new to wordpress. I hope You can understand my question.. Is there a way I can access the existing navigation bar to make changes? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In your dashboard, go to Appearance > Menus and ensure you have created a menu, add the pages to that menu and then depending on the theme you are using, specify where you want it to appear.